# Application specific exception wrapping "MongoDuplicateKeyException" not catch'ed

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Out of need have created application exception which wraps a `MongoDuplicateKeyException` and throwing that exception like below

```
Public class AppException : Exception
{
  // all constructor implementation 

  public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
  public string AppMessage { get; set; }
}
```

In method catching and throwing exception

```
public async Task<Response> Method1(parameter ...)
{
  try
   {
      //some insert/update operation to DB 
      return <instance of Response>;
   }
  catch(MongoduplicateKeyException ex)
  {
    var exception = new AppException(ex.Message, ex)
    {
      ErrorCode = 22,
      AppMessage = "some message",
    };

    throw exception;
  }
}
```

Method that calls `Method1()` above

```
try
{
  //some other operation
  var response = await Method1();
}
catch(AppException ex)
{
  SomeOtherLoggingMethod(ex, other parameter);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  SomeMethod(ex, other parameter);
}
```

Surprisingly the `catch(AppException ex)` catch block never gets catched even though am throwing an `AppException` from `Method1()`. It always catch the generic catch block `catch(Exception ex)`.

After debugging, found that in `catch(Exception ex)` catch block the exception type `ex.GetType()` is actually a `WriteConcernException` type (`MongoduplicateKeyException : WriteConcernException`).

So essentially that specific catch block not hitting cause the exception type is not `AppException` rather `WriteConcernException` **But**

Not sure why is it so? am I missing something obvious here? Please suggest.

Comment: When you change `public async Task<Response> Method1(parameter ...)` to `public void Method1(parameter ...)` the behavior is the same?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, not tried but how should that matter BTW?

Comment: I'm thinking about some concept of the async/await pattern/implementation that we don't have noticed... Just in case.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, got what you mean but in that case the generic exception itself would have not get caught

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the answer while debugging. The `catch(AppException ex)` block is not executed because `public async Task<Response> Method1` does not throw an AppException it throws a WriteConcernException.

[The API shows](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/WriteConcernException.html) a WriteConcernException is the superclass of DuplicateKeyException so the catch block in Method1 is not hit and the exception bubbles up to the 2nd catch block in the caller.

So if you update your code to catch the appropriate exception it should work as you intend.

```
public async Task<Response> Method1(parameter ...)
{
    try
    {
        //some insert/update operation to DB
        return <instance of Response>;
    }
    catch (MongoServerException mse)
    ...
```

Comment: *Method1 does not throw an AppException* ... how? I am wrapping the actual dupkey exception to app specific exception and throwing that. do you mean I should be catching `Writeconcernexception` instead? am not sure why you think so

Comment: Paul is right. The MongoduplicateKeyException inherites from WriteConcernException (Any other class can inherite from it too), the catch block of your Method1 is not being hitten

Comment: Yep, you are right but looks like I will have to catch `MongoWriteException` instead. edit that in your answer , so that can mark it answer

Comment: @Rahul You are not wrapping a DuplicateKeyException because that exception type is not being thrown. Put a breakpoint where you create the AppException and you'll see that code is not hit. Instead a WriteConcernException is thrown and it bubbles up until it finds a catch block that can catch it

Comment: @Rahul I changed it to MongoServerException as that will cover both MongoWriteException and WriteConcernException/DuplicateKeyException. If you feel this is too broad you could add a second catch block instead